# Angular 6 typescript listen event when window print is cancelled (click on cancel print)

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, angular6

I am trying to redirect after window.print is open, when the user clicks on cancel.

this opens the window print

```
printHc(){
  window.print();
}
```

now if the user cancel print I want to redirect to another route. e.g.

```
this.router.navigate("other_page");
```

How can I listen to this event on typescript in Angular 6 (using chrome)?

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of afterprint event. The event is fired both when the user prints or canceles the print dialog.

```
  @HostListener('window:afterprint')
  onafterprint() {
    this.router.navigate("other_page");
  }
```